# problem with converting .dat file to .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

hi guys im trying to convert the .dat file to . csv however im unable to. Please bear with me as im still a beginner in python.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

with open('blk01530.dat','r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)

print(df)
```

and here is the error i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sunqinan/Desktop/FYP/convertdat.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 445, in __init__
    data = list(data)
  File "/Users/sunqinan/Desktop/FYP/convertdat.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

please do help me as i've been trying for hours on this and this is how my .dat file looks like

```
1 f9be b4d9 4243 1300 0000 0020 5f7f ef93
2 ff4f 1dc9 dd08 3798 9dbe f46a 2b6d 1b8c
3 2a08 1c00 0000 0000 0000 0000 9763 8a53
4 c3c1 8718 9b60 c677 2d4a 648a d3ce a6ba
5 d936 e047 28d0 7f57 93b9 433f eeb8 665c
6 886f 2e17 4381 e91a fd5f 0b01 0000 0000
7 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: is the dat file contains non ascii characters ?. Can you try ```df = pd.DataFrame([l.encode('utf-8').rstrip().split() for l in f])```

Comment: @pavan kumar i tried but it return the same error

Comment: I can think of possible encoding issue during open but can't be sure. Pasted dat file will work fine because when you copied and pasted, the text is automatically converted to accepted format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all DataFrame takes a list, so you need to do a proper list comprehension. Try the following:

```
with open('blk01530.dat', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([l.rstrip() for l in f.read().split()])
```

Comment: by the way your naming is not Pythonic, be more explicit to what the meaning is of `l` and `f`

Comment: hi thanks for the comment but this is the error i got AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: well the original error appeared after changing that line of code.
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte